# MySQL - Select & Update

Tags: mysql

So I've got a database where all weights were entered in ounces when the shipping calculator uses pounds. So I wrote this query to divide all the weights by 16 using SELECT:

```
SELECT ( weight / 16 ) AS weight FROM product_details;
```

This gives me all the values as a query result, but what I really want is to actually update all the values as part of that query. Any ideas?

Comment: You mean to use the `UPDATE` statement?: `UPDATE product_details SET weight = weight / 16`

Answer (score 4):

Just convert it into an `UPDATE` statement. Add a WHERE clause to only affect certain rows, if appropriate.

```
UPDATE product_details SET weight = (weight / 16) WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
UPDATE product_details SET weight = weight / 16
```